# Создание QLabel поверх главного виджета

Tags: c++, qt

Есть основной виджет, который скомпонован с помощью layout-ов и я хочу, чтобы во время выполнения соновной программы при определенных обстоятельствах поверх основного окна всплавала `QLabel` с нужным уведомлением. Для этого пытался сделать что-то вроде:

```
::QLabel lbl(wgt);
lbl.setText("info");
lbl.show;
```

Но в результате `lbl` оказывается под элементами скомпонованными с помощью layout-ов.

PS создание отдельного окна для `label` (не входящего в основной) не рассматривается.

Comment: я имею ввиду, что это label должен быть в том же окне поверх основого виджета

Comment: Добавьте Ваш Label в то же размещение (layout) и включайте/выключайте его с помощью show/hide. Либо же добавьте Label поверх виджета в окне, которое этот виджет содержит. И так же включайте/выключайте его.

Comment: @ixSci первый способ однозначно нет, так как label должен быть поверх - так же элементы сместятся. А второе - вопрос то как раз таки в том: как это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте `lbl.raise();`

Comment: @ixSci спасибо - то что надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, это должно вам помочь: 
[QWidget::raise()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#raise)